# import class from php on web server with allow_url_open off

Tags: php

okay i solved this by uploading the lib file inside a folder and addressing it as '//'

damn, i am so happy!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :D :D :D :D :D

i uploaded this code file named post.php and the file it needs tmhOAuth to the host(eu5.org) under root directory and set permissions to 755 on both:
i run the script from my site .eu5.org/post.php but get the below error

```
<?php

$tweet_text = 'Hello Twitter';
print "Posting...\n";
$result = post_tweet($tweet_text);
print "Response code: " . $result . "\n";

function post_tweet($tweet_text) {

require_once('ftp://<username>.eu5.org@eu5.org/tmhOAuth.php');
  $connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
    'consumer_key' => '******',
    'consumer_secret' => '******',
    'user_token' => '******',
    'user_secret' => '******',
  )); 

  $connection->request('POST', 
    $connection->url('1/statuses/update'), 
    array('status' => $tweet_text));

  return $connection->response['code'];
}
?>
```

> Warning: require_once() [function.require-once]: ftp:// wrapper is
>   disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in
>   .php on line 8
>
> Warning: require_once(.php) [function.require-once]: failed
>   to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in .php on
>   line 8
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required '.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in  on
>   line 8

note: allow_url_open is off.
how do i import the class? using curl etc.?
thanks

Comment: Please show your code. Why is it trying to use some URL wrapper to `include` a file?

Comment: don't you have permission to update php.ini file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to include (or require, it's only a matter of error reporting) a file, it is strictly useless (and nonesense) to use urls.
your library must be on YOUR server, let's say in the directory `library/'.

Your code would be that one :

```
include('library/yourfile.php');
//or require('library/yourfile.php'); if you prefere fatal errors over warnings
```